# QSerialPort::readLine doesn't work as expected on MS Windows

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port, qtserialport

I'm trying to connect a micro-controller with my desktop PC via USB-serial cable.
The OS of my desktop PC is Windows 8.1, and USB-serial cable is TTL-232R-3V3. (FTDI)
(Qt version: 5.2.0 beta1, QtCreator Version: 3.0, Compiler: MSVC2012)

Now I'm trying read/write loop-back tests, and that's why RX/TX pin of USB-serial cable are connected with each other.

Here is my code.

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPort>
#include <QtSerialPort/QSerialPortInfo>
#include <QtCore/QDebug>

#define PORT_NAME "COM3"
#define BAUDRATE 19600
#define TIMEOUT_MS 1000

QT_USE_NAMESPACE
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QSerialPort pSerial(PORT_NAME);
    const char strMsg[] = "#1:Send data line \n #2:Send data line\n #3:Send data line end\n";
    char strBuf[256];
    qint64 nByte;


    if(pSerial.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)){
        pSerial.setBaudRate(BAUDRATE);
        qDebug() << "OPEN PASS";

        pSerial.write(strMsg);
        pSerial.flush();
        if(pSerial.waitForBytesWritten(TIMEOUT_MS)){
            qDebug() << "WRITE PASS";
        }


        pSerial.waitForReadyRead(TIMEOUT_MS);
        while(true){
            if( pSerial.canReadLine()){
                qDebug() << "CAN READ LINE";
                nByte = pSerial.readLine(strBuf,sizeof(strBuf));
                qDebug() << "Length: " << nByte;
                qDebug() << "Read data: " << strBuf;

            }
        }
        pSerial.close();
    } else {
        qDebug() << "OPEN FAIL\n";
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

When the program starts to run, the result is different than I expected. 
Only first line of sent data can be received. So, "Read data: #1 Send data line" is printed
on console. But the rest of sent data will never be received. Does anyone know why?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I revised my code according to Papp's comment.Then it works as I expected. 
All sent message has been received.

Does it mean I misunderstand the usage about readLine() or canReadLine()?

```
//        while(true){
//            if( pSerial.canReadLine()){
//                qDebug() << "CAN READ LINE";
//                nByte = pSerial.readLine(strBuf,sizeof(strBuf));
//                qDebug() << "Length: " << nByte;
//                qDebug() << "Read data: " << strBuf;
//            }
//        }

        pSerial.waitForReadyRead(TIMEOUT_MS);
        QByteArray readData = pSerial.readAll();
        while (pSerial.waitForReadyRead(TIMEOUT_MS)) {
            readData.append(pSerial.readAll());
        }
        qDebug() << "Read data: " << readData;
```

**EDIT 2nd time** : Following code also works for me.

```
while(true){
    if( pSerial.waitForReadyRead(TIMEOUT_MS) && pSerial.canReadLine()){ // I revised this line
        qDebug() << "CAN READ LINE";
        nByte = pSerial.readLine(strBuf,sizeof(strBuf));
        qDebug() << "Length: " << nByte;
        qDebug() << "Read data: " << strBuf;
        qDebug() << "Error Message: " << pSerial.errorString();

    }
}
```

Comment: Flow control?  Have you disabled it?

Comment: @JoeZ Thank you for your comment. At first, I didn't assign　any flag about the flow control. Then I added the following code.But it doesn't work for me. pSerial.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::SoftwareControl); or pSerial.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);

Comment: @yufit_in_Japan: I gave +1, but have you tried to read in a loop, like:     QByteArray readData = serialPort.readAll();
    while (serialPort.waitForReadyRead(5000))
        readData.append(serialPort.readAll()); Does such a thing work, i.e. can we make sure it is really a readLine issue? Also, does it work on Unix? What is the value of nByte for the second time? Have you checked the errorString just in case if that does not succeed, or it succeeds with zero character? Btw, the error management is quite sloppy in your code.

Comment: @LaszloPapp : Thanks a lot. According to your comment, I revised the source code. Although I don't understand  why the problem occurs, I can make progress.

Comment: @LaszloPapp : When I try the same code (readline() ver.) on Ubuntu 13.10, it works as I expected. This result is diffrent from that of MS Windows.(I revised this comment later because it turned out to be a mistake.)

Comment: @yufit_in_Japan: it might be a bug. Free feel to report it, and we will take a look at it for 5.2.1. In the meantime, you can use the workaround below. Although you have not replied yet to the nByte question. What is its value when you would expect further reads? If not erronous, then print out pSerial.errorString() and let me know.

Comment: @LaszloPapp : Sorry for my late reply about the nByte question. In the original source code (readLine() ver.), pSerial.canReadLine() becomes true just one time. As a result, the readLine() will never be called at second time.  I cannot answer your question. Please let me know if I misunderstand what you said. By the way, I discover the alternative solution for this problem. I added source code again.

Comment: @yufit_in_Japan: hmm, sounds like a bug on Windows. I will take a look into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you need to read in a loop like this:

```
QByteArray readData = serialPort.readAll();
while (serialPort.waitForReadyRead(5000))
    readData.append(serialPort.readAll());
```

Please see the `creadersync` example for the details what I added to 5.2. You can also check the `creaderasync` example for non-blocking operation.

To be fair, we have not tested readLine that much, but it works for me on Unix, so does it on Windows for someone else.

Comment: How does this help with reading lines?? This answer completely misses the point.

Comment: The OP had trouble with his line reading code. Your answer does not address that at all, you offer a different solution that ignores the line reading aspect. It's valid code, of course, but nothing to do with line reading. In my book that's missing the point. How is pointing the obvious and plainly visible facts considered aggressive or ignorant I wouldn't know.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake that you've made is expecting to receive all the sent data when `waitForReadyRead` returns. When `waitForReadyRead` finishes, all you're guaranteed is *some data* being available to be read. It may be as little as one character, not necessarily a whole line.

The loop from your last modification is the *almost* correct way to do it. You should nest reading of the lines in a separate loop. The following code is how it should be done, and agrees with the semantics of `QIODevice`:

```
while (pSerial.waitForReadyRead(TIMEOUT_MS)) {
  while (pSerial.canReadLine()) {
    qDebug() << "NEW LINE";
    QByteArray line = pSerial.readLine();
    qDebug() << "Length: " << line.size();
    qDebug() << "Read data: " << line;
    qDebug() << "Error Message: " << pSerial.errorString();
  }
}
qDebug << "TIMED OUT";
```

Note that none of this code should even run in the GUI thread. Ideally you should move it to a QObject, use the signals emitted by `QIODevice` (and thus `QSerialPort`), and move that object to a separate thread.

The GUI thread can sometimes block for long periods of time, it's not normally desirable to have it disturb the timeliness of your device communication. Similarly, you don't want device timeouts to block the GUI thread. Both are equally bad and are a very common source of **bad user experience**. Qt makes multithreading very easy - leverage it for your user's sake, and do it properly.

Comment: Have you actually read what the OP wrote? Your assumption does not make any sense since the write happened in a sync operation, and even moreover: the OP only gets one line. I do not understand the point of this answer respectively. Not to mention, the ui thread vs. non ui thread is a red herring here. That is in not any way relevant to canReadLine and readLine since it should work in both cases.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: The question was about reading lines, there isn't a single relevant mention of reading lines in your answer. The fact that the write was synchronous doesn't mean much. Just because a sync write has "returned" doesn't mean that the bytes have actually moved to the receive buffers in a loopback scenario. Heck, it doesn't even mean that they've left the USB host. The mention of the UI thread is relevant - I'm pointing out that one shouldn't put blocking code there. It may or may not apply, I'm mentioning it just in case.

Comment: You really do not listen, neither to the OP, nor me: as written, the OP received one line (and randomly as your answer assumes mistakenly). Eventually, your code is even worse: it would not wait for input to come over a certain timeout which is not what the OP wanted. Moreover, mentioning all the imaginary and theoretical cases which is not relevant to the real problem at hand is superfluous.

Comment: s/randomly/not randomly/

Answer (score 0):

On Linux I have to do it this way to receive ASCII text ending with `'\n'`

```
QByteArray readData = pSerial.readAll();
while (readData[readData.length() - 1] != '\n') {
    pSerial.waitForReadyRead(5000);
    readData.append(pSerial.readAll());
}
QString result(readData);
```

`QSerialPort::readLine()` doesn't work for me either